# How to hit any customize port from your Ionic application

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to hit localhost at another port than 8100 via my Ionic Application but it refused to connect with the port. Want to know how to achieve this.

Appreciate for help...

Comment: Be more precise please. Are you talking about `ionic serve` or browser platform ? What have you tried that doesn't work ?

Comment: Be more precise and let us know what you have try so far .. and what exactly the error message is

Comment: No, I am not talking about ionic serve. I want to hit the biometric device port with my ionic application which is installed on my android device. But when I hit that port its refused my connection "Connection Refused" with the port.

Comment: What is the port number and please share your code how you are trying to connect and .. what exactly the error message

Comment: const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "https://127.0.0.1:11101"
    xhr.open('DEVICEINFO', url);
    const params = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <PidOptions ver="1.0"> <Opts fCount="' + 5 + '" fType="' + "FMR" + '" iCount="' + 1 + '" pCount="' + 1 + '" format="' + 0 + '"   pidVer="' + 2.0 + '" timeout="' + 60000 + '" posh="UNKNOWN" env="' + 'P' + '" /> ' + 'this.DemoFinalString' + '<CustOpts><Param name="mantrakey" value="' + '' + '" /></CustOpts> </PidOptions>';
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xhr.send(params);